# How to pass User ID which is not assigned in view>Model from Controller in MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

That is my Change Pass ViewModel.

```
public class ChangePasswordViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Current password")]
    public string OldPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "New password")]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm new password")]
    [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

and I redirectAction to ChangePass controller with Login ID like that >>

```
return RedirectToAction("ChangePassword", new { id = loginuser[0].PkUserAcc });
```

In my Change Pass get method >>

```
public ActionResult ChangePassword(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    tblUserAcc tbluseracc = db.tblUserAccs.Find(id);
    if (tbluseracc == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I used ChangePasswordViewModel in ChangePassword View>>

```
@model IBS.Models.ChangePasswordViewModel
```

URL like that>>

```
http://localhost:63855/User/ChangePassword/2
```

My Problem is >>

1. Can I get LoginID (2) from Post method?
2. Need to pass LoginID to view form ChangePass(get method) and how to pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property to your model for the ID

```
public class ChangePasswordViewModel
{
  public int ID { get; set; } // add this
  [Required]
  [DataType(DataType.Password)]
  [Display(Name = "Current password")]
  public string OldPassword { get; set; }
```

Then in your GET method

```
public ActionResult ChangePassword(int? id)
{
  if (id == null)
  {
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
  }
  tblUserAcc tbluseracc = db.tblUserAccs.Find(id);
  if (tbluseracc == null)
  {
      return HttpNotFound();
  }
  ChangePasswordViewModel model = new ChangePasswordViewModel();
  model.ID = id;
  return View(model);
}
```

If you have the default route with `defaults: new { controller = "..", action = "..", id = UrlParameter.Optional }`, then the `ID` will be added to the route values and the model will be bound with the ID when you post back. If not, then you need to add a hidden input for the value (or ad it to the route values)

Answer (score 0):

you may use [Viewbag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag(v=vs.118).aspx)

set in your controller first.

```
..
ViewBag.LoginID  = tbluseracc.Id;
return View();
```

and in your view

```
...
<input id="loginId" type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.LoginID"/>
```

from then you can pass it again in your post method..